# Nginx with Slim framework - php files getting downloaded

Tags: php, nginx, raspberry-pi, slim

I'm trying to setup a simple REST api for a database connection and have decided to do so by using nginx and the Slim framework. Installed both (slim locally in a project directory via the Composer dependency manager `/home/some_user/slim_project/`).

After that I tried to implement the Slim code-example and followed a couple guides doing so, but with all my attempts I ended up failing. Either the php-file gets downloaded or i simply get the Slim `"Page not found"` page.

The project is running on a raspberry pi with a dynamic DNS configured.

My structure and code looks like this:

> /home/some_user/slim_project/public/index.php

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, 
array $args) {
    $name = $args['name'];
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

and the nginx config:

> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /home/some_user/slim_test/public/;

        server_name mySlimTest1.ddns.net;

        location / {
                if (!-e $request_filename){
                        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
                }
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Whatever I try, all that happens is the php-file getting downloaded or in some cases I get a 404 when I add the exemplary '/hello/Hans' to the end of the server url.

I followed this tutorial for example: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/tutorial/first-app.html
I am clearly missing something here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rewrite...break` causes the new URI to be processed in the same location, you should use `rewrite...last` when internally redirecting to a `.php` URI from a different `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

However, your `if` block performs a similar function to `try_files`. The same functionality can be achieved with the following:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```